# MBProgressHUD with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: asihttprequest, mbprogresshud

I am trying to use MBProgressHUD to display a progress of download of multiple images which are downloaded via ASINetworkQueue.

I have set the hud as networkQueue's progress delegate and I have also set the mode of the hud to MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate.

I can make the hud display and hide, but I cannot change the progress. The hud just doesn't redraw itself until the networkQueue is complete.

I can see that MBProgressHUD's drawRect is never called but I don't know why.

I would be very grateful if anyone could provide a sample or pseudo code of how to achieve this.

Thanks,

Andrius

Answer (score 0):

There are perhaps two likely issues:

1. The main thread of your application has been blocked; are you calling 'waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished' on the main thread or similar?
2. ASIHTTPRequest can't report much in the way of progress if the server isn't sending Content-Length: headers, so this could also be the issue.

Comment: Ok, I have played a little bit with my program and have found out that the problem is most likely related to threading. I initiate the network queue on a method which is a success method from a previous ASIHTTPRequest. If I execute the method myself (like by pressing a button), the progress is shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well now I have managed to narrow my searches to this: the problem really is inside this method: [downloadRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageDownloadComplete:)]; inside this method I have a call: [viewHolder.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; If I comment this line, the progress is shown.